# Can I use languagetool for android app development

Tags: java, android, languagetool

I used languagetool 3.4 API for my desktop application, now I want to use it in my android app. Is it possible? if so, how to use it? I am using Android Studio.

Thanks

Comment: At least a year ago it didn't work, see https://github.com/languagetool-org/languagetool/issues/330

Comment: Is there any other API or library which I can use to figure out grammatical mistakes in the text?

Comment: Does it really have to be on the device? LanguageTool has a server mode that returns JSON. We have a list of alternative Open Source text checkers at http://wiki.languagetool.org/other-open-source-grammar-checkers

Comment: Actually I want my app to work offline.