# Can I use LanguageTool in android studio

Tags: android, languagetool

Can I use LanguageTool in my android studio project. I need to check grammar of text.

Thank you in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459226/can-i-use-languagetool-for-android-app-development

Comment: any reference to what LanguageTool is?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand anything from that link.It will be great if you elaborate those things to me. and thank for your fast reply.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko - LanguageTool is a grammatical checker writtern in java.

Answer (score 0):

The link provided by @NileshRathod (and the github issues it links to) says that it currently does not work.

The LanguageTool issue has been closed:

```
https://github.com/languagetool-org/languagetool/issues/330
```

and refiled upstream:

```
https://github.com/icenlp/segment/issues/1
```

That project hasn't been updated in the last 7 years though, so I wouldn't hold my breath.